# Importing package with same base package name

Tags: python, package

I have a large library I want to split up. There are packages:
`hdx.data`
`hdx.facades`
`hdx.utilities`

I want to move hdx.utilities to a separate project hdx-python-utilities (on PyPi) and then add it as a requirement to the project with the packages hdx.data and hdx.facades (hdx-python-api). The problem is that I get `ImportError: No module named 'hdx.utilities'` when doing `from hdx.utilities.session import get_session` in the project hdx-python-api.

Is there any way to make this work in both Python 3+ and 2.7 (without renaming the top level package name hdx in either of them) allowing both hdx-python-api and hdx-python-utilities to work in any project that installs them?

Comment: Why would you want to separate it out only to make it a requirement?

Comment: So that the utilities it contains can be used in other projects (without importing hdx-python-api)

Comment: You may have to *install* `hdx-python-api` but you won't be *importing* it.

Comment: Yes I meant install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are three ways of doing namespaced packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#creating-a-namespace-package):

- Native (Python 3.3)
- pkgutil-style (Python 2 and 3, compatible to native)
- pkg_resources-style (incompatible to the above, deprecated, not recommended)

The recommended way of doing namespaced packages for Python 2 and 3 are [pkgutil-style namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/#pkgutil-style-namespace-packages):

You would create the following for `hpx-python-api`

```
setup.py
hpx/
    __init__.py     # namespace init, see content below
    data/
        __init__.py
        ...
    facades/
        __init__.py
        ...
```

and the following for `hpx-python-utilities`

```
setup.py
hpx/
    __init__.py     # namespace init, see content below
    utilities/
        __init__.py
        ...
```

The two `__init__.py` files for the namespace package needs to contain only the following:

```
__path__ = __import__('pkgutil').extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Comment: Thx alot. Very helpful!

Comment: If you still get import errors, I found that you need to recreate your virtualenv (even if you had updated your packages to the right versions).

Comment: Also if you want to use any subpackage name in two projects (eg. create `hdx.utilities` in two projects) then the `__init__.py` in the subpackage must also contain the `__path__` line (like the `__init__.py` in the base package eg. `hdx` in the example).